# parsing 1000000 xml document with DOCTYPE

Tags: xml

I have one million xml files that I can't parse because they have a Doctype so my program has a lot of errors. I don't know what should I do?

Thanks for your help

my xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE WEBIR SYSTEM "webir.dtd">
<school>
<student id="1">
<firstname>ankush</firstname>
<lastname>thakur</lastname>
<email>beingjavaguy.gmail.com</email>
<phone>7678767656</phone>
</student>
```

Comment: What programm language do you want to use? What have you tried? Try being more specific.

Comment: The XML seems not to be valid, independent of the dtd, as the closing `</school>`-tag is missing. Might this be the reason for the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Use a catalog to redirect the reference to webir.dtd to a dummy DTD that allows any content.

See for example

http://www.scriptorium.com/2009/09/ignoring-doctype-in-xsl-transforms-using-saxon-9b/